# Why am I getting a segfault (binary data parsing) c

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm scanning through raw bits 512 bytes at a time.  If the first 4 bytes match the jpeg file suffix I create a new jpeg and write that block and all following blocks to it, until I encounter a new jpeg suffix.

For some reason it segfaults on the read call that follows the first write call.

/**
     * recover.c
     *
     * Computer Science 50
     * Problem Set 4
     *
     * Recovers JPEGs from a forensic image.
     */

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef uint8_t  BYTE;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //load in file
    FILE* file = fopen("card.raw", "r");
    FILE* newfile = NULL;

    //error opening file
    if (file==NULL){
        return 1;
    }

    //create buffer and outfile index
    BYTE buffer[512]; //
    int filecount = 0;
    char newfilename[3];

    //iterate through file, break on eof
    while (1){//(!feof(file)){//(fgetc(file) != EOF){

        //seek back to 512 block start
        //fseek(file,-1,SEEK_CUR);
        //fread(&buffer,1,512,file);
        if (fread(buffer,512,1,file) <= 0){
            break;
        }

        //Check if first 4 bytes are jpeg signature
        if ((buffer[0] == 0xff &&
             buffer[1] == 0xd8 &&
             buffer[2] == 0xff &&
             buffer[3] == 0xe0)||
            (buffer[0] == 0xff &&
             buffer[1] == 0xd8 &&
             buffer[2] == 0xff &&
             buffer[3] == 0xe1 )){

            //close out previously created jpeg
            if (newfile != NULL){
                //file close error
                if (fclose(newfile) == EOF){
                    return 2;
                }
                newfile = NULL;
            }

            //create new jpeg
            sprintf(newfilename,"%03d.jpeg",filecount++);
            newfile = fopen(newfilename,"w");

        }

        //Write blocks to newfile
        if (newfile != NULL){
            if (fwrite(buffer,512,1,newfile) <= 0){
                return 4;
            }

        }
    }

    //close out last newfile 
    if (newfile != NULL){
        //file close error
        if (fclose(newfile) == EOF){
            return 3;
        }
        newfile = NULL;
    }

    //close infile
    fclose(file);



//we should find 16 images


}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `valgrind` to see if you have invalid memory accesses?

Comment: If you don't know what [valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org) check the link. And why you and so many others do this `if (fread(buffer,512,1,file) <= 0){break;}` kind of thing? Just `whie (fread(buffer,512,1,file) > 0)` is easier to understand, I don't see the purpose of an infinite loop that is not infinite at all, and I am curious where do people learn that?

Comment: I've not followed all the code, I see that you declare "char newfilename[3];" and then you use "sprintf(newfilename,"%03d.jpeg",filecount++);"! newfilename would have a dimension of at least 10 bytes. Furthermore, if filecount becomes greater than 999, you need that the buffer is 11 bytes and so on!

Comment: Sergio, this was indeed the problem :)

Comment: iharob, thank you, I didn't know I could do that.  I thought it might continue looping with EOF but even then I can use != size_num

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not enough array for the filename with

```
char newfilename[3];
```

when you do

```
sprintf(newfilename,"%03d.jpeg",filecount++);
```

which will require

```
char newfilename[9];
```

Comment: not necessarily, because if `filecount > 999` it will overflow the `newfilename` anyway, I would recommend `snprintf()`.

Comment: Yes, I was going to add "why be mean, make it reasonably large?"

Comment: 10 bytes not 9 ... !!! There's a \0 at the end of all C string! Furthermore if filecount++ becomes greater than 999 ... ;)

Comment: @SergioFormiggini. `"123.jpeg\0"` is 9 chars, pushing the number past 999 is stretching the question too far, and all your comments are posted 5 minutes after similar comments.

Comment: But remains the problems if filecount++ exceeds 999!

Comment: @SergioFormiggini. Which is what **iharob** wrote 14 minutes ago. By specifying `%03d` OP is obviously not processing 1000 files!

Comment: @ Weather Vane! ... And Is what i said above (in the question) 15 minutes ago ... :)